# Laravel utf-8 saving with unknown characters

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, utf-8

I'm trying to save article in sinhala language which belongs to the charset "unicode" and get back the saved information via laravel. But when i'm saving, my data is saving with some kind of unknown tags. Please help me to solve this issue. Below is the picture of returning data. I set my database collation to utf8_general_ci and set encoding of every page into utf8 also. But issue is still there.

[image]

and below is my saving method in laravel.

```
public function store()
{
    $input = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all();

    $input['published_at']=Carbon::now();
    Article::create($input);

    return redirect('articles');
    }
```

and below is my method of getting the result

```
public function show($id)
{
    $article = Article::findOrFail($id);

    return view('articles.show', compact('article'));
}
```

Comment: what is your table collation ??

Comment: Have you followed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through? How are you testing the output? What should the output look like?

Comment: What are the unknown tags?  `<p>` and `<span>` are well known.